# Object value is not preserved from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using a model to pass values from controller to model. Say I have a first controller action method :

```
    public ActionResult CreateADForm(SiteDirectionModel model){
        MyModel myModel= new MyModel{
            id = model.id, 
            name = model.name,
            //an so on
            siteDirection = model //a SiteDirectionModel object
        };
        return View(myModel);
    }
```

The point of this method is to preload some values and then pass it to a view with a form :

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateForm", "Create", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.name, new { @class= "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Créer l'utilisateur" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

My problem is that now when I validate this form, I try to retrieve `SiteDirectionModel siteDirection` but it is always null. I wanted to do that, so that in case the form is not valid, then I return to the form with errors shown (like textboxes not filled for example), but it's dysfunctional. I'm guessing that the values have to be attributed when filling the form which is why I keep getting null, but have you any idea how to do this?

Comment: What's your `SiteDirectionModel` look like?  The only form element here is a single text input called `name`.

Comment: A for only posts back the name/value pairs of its form controls. If you do not create for controls for each property of `SiteDirectionModel` then it will not be bound. But in any case, you should only be posting back the ID of that `SiteDirectionModel`

Comment: @David I minimized to make it testable. But `SiteDirectionModel` has 20+ variables.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Why only the ID? You mean ID of `MyModel` no?

Comment: Are you wrapping your EF model inside of your view model?

Comment: No, just the ID of your `SiteDirectionModel` - including all that extra html in the view and sending it back again is just degrading performance. If for some reason you need that model again, just get it from the database based on the ID

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh yeah, good idea thank you

Comment: @Fran Some of it yes. I put data from DB and variables for the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form validation happens after the roundtrip to the server is complete (i.e. after form POST).
Therefore you have to send all values back to the server that you require in the receiving action.

Add hidden fields for the properties of `siteDirection` you need.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.siteDirection.Name)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.siteDirection.Value)
@* ... *@
```

Alternatively, send the ID of the siteDirection and load this entity from the DB again.

Comment: So I've tried using `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.id)` so that I can reload the entries from my db, but the id retrieved in my controller action method is always null

Comment: This is weird, is the `id` set correctly in  `MyModel myModel= new MyModel{ id = model.id };` ?

Comment: Yes, I pass it successfully and it has a value in my view. I tried also `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.id, new { @Value = Model.id})` to no avail

Comment: Ah, I found my mistake, it came from a wrong use of `RedirectToAction`. Thanks!